# Repeat for loop for all rows of a spatial points data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to calculate the shortestPath distance (using gDistance package) between a set of geographic coordinates, using a transition layer of the ocean to prevent 'movement' across land.

Here is how I created the transition layer:

```
library(raster); library(gdistance); library(maptools); library(rgdal); library(sp)
mapcrs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
data(wrld_simpl)
world <- wrld_simpl
worldshp <- spTransform(world, mapcrs)
ras <- raster(nrow=300,ncol=300)
crs(ras) <- crs(oceans.shp)
extent(ras) <- extent(worldshp)
landmask <- rasterize(worldshp, ras)
landras <- is.na(landmask)
tr <- transition(landras, transitionFunction = mean, directions = 8, symm = FALSE)
tr = geoCorrection(tr, scl=FALSE)
```

I then want to calculate the shortestPath distance between every coordinate in my dataset i.e. location 1 to location n, location 2 to location n etc.

Let's produce some hypothetical geographic coordinates and convert to spatial points

```
x <- rnorm(10, mean = -40, sd=5)
y <- rnorm(10, mean = 20, sd=5)
xy <- cbind(x,y); colnames(xy) <- c("lon","lat")
xy <- SpatialPoints(xy); projection(xy) <- projection(mapcrs)
```

Using the shortestPath function in gDistance, I can calculate the distance from the first coordinate (i.e. xy[1]) to all other xy coordinates, like so.

```
dist <- shortestPath(tr, origin = xy, goal = xy, output="SpatialLines")
```

I then tried to apply a for loop to sequentially calculate distance from location 1 to all other locations, and then calculating distance from location 2 to all other locations etc., which I wrote as follows:

```
for(i in seq_along(xy)){
  AtoB <- shortestPath(tr, origin = xy[i,], goal=xy, output="SpatialLines")
  i <- i+1
}
```

This, however, still only calculates the distances relative to the first xy spatial point and does not 'loop' for all subsequent rows. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's probably super-easy, but I'm struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tony

---- UPDATE ----

We have come up with a bit of a work around (thanks Charley Clubley) but it still won't produce outputs for every spatial line. This will generate a matrix of distances.

The work around is as follows:

### Using xy as a matrix, not spatial points

```
distances <- matrix(ncol=nrow(xy), nrow=nrow(xy))

xy_b <- xy ## Coords needs to be as a matrix (not spatial points)

## This generates an error indicating there are no more rows to delete once complete, but the computation works

for (i in 1:nrow(xy_b)) {
  AtoB <-shortestPath(tr, xy_b, xy, output="SpatialLines")
  length <- SpatialLinesLengths(AtoB)
  distances[i, ] <- length
  xy_b <- xy_b[-1,]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Not super easy, or everything is easy once you know how it is done. First, agreeing that distances measured on unprojected maps (our crs here) will, WILL lead to civilian casualties, try slipping a second loop inside your i loop, call it k or m or something, and iterate by [i, k]. `gdistance` took a surprisingly long time to build so only just getting to playing with your code...

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for responding. I think we have come up with a work around, where we delete the first row of the coordinates after each loop iteration, but I still don't understand why it won't work using the standard syntax. Perhaps a restriction with the shortestPath function?